# Autorest.PowerShell: build module failed because invalid variable generated

Tags: c#, powershell, swagger, swagger-codegen, autorest

When I want to generate PowerShell module from my swagger

I try to run `Generate-PowerShellClient.ps1` and see below logs

```
   BSN.IpTables.Cli   Feature/22-add-cli≡  ~1  .\Generate-PowerShellClient.ps1                                                                                                                                                                    

changed 1 package in 222ms
AutoRest code generation utility [cli version: 3.6.3; node: v18.15.0]
(C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation.
https://aka.ms/autorest
info    |    Loading AutoRest core      'C:\Users\sooro\.autorest\@autorestcore@3.9.7\nodemodules\@autorest\core\dist' (3.9.7)
info    |
The default version of @autorest/powershell has been bumped from 2.1+ to 3.0+.
 > If you still want to use 2.1+ version, please specify it with --use:@autorest/powershell@2.1.{x}, e.g 2.1.401.

info    |    Loading AutoRest extension '@autorest/powershell' (4.0.648->4.0.648)
info    |    Loading AutoRest extension '@autorest/modelerfour' (~4.26.0->4.26.2)
verbose | [1.47 s] Reading OpenAPI 3.0 file file:///D:/Source/Repos/Resa/IpTables.Api/Source/BSN.IpTables.Api/swagger.json
warning | PreCheck/CheckDuplicateSchemas | Checking for duplicate schemas, this could take a (long) while.  Run with --verbose for more detail.
verbose | [1.63 s] Found and removed 0 duplicate schema
warning | UsingTemporaryFlag | modelerfour.treat-type-object-as-anything options is a temporary flag. It WILL be removed in the future.
verbose | [1.78 s]   ModelerFour/api-version-mode:client
verbose | [1.78 s]   ModelerFour/api-version-parameter:constant
verbose | [1.78 s]   ModelerFour/use-model-namespace:false
info    | Autorest completed in 2.54s. 211 files generated.
```

as you can see above, autorest PowerShell extension generate my module without any errors

then When I try to build this module with `build-module.ps1`, I got below errors

```
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(63,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(63,54): error CS1073: Unexpected token '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(63,54): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(116,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(116,54): error CS1073: Unexpected token '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(116,54): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(179,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(179,54): error CS1073: Unexpected token '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(179,54): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(242,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(242,54): error CS1073: Unexpected token '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(242,54): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(295,54): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(295,54): error CS1073: Unexpected token '$' [D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\BsnIPTablesCli.csproj]
D:\Source\Repos\Resa\IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs(295,54): error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
```

After I some investigation, I found my errors exist because autorest powershell module use `$host` variable in `IpTables.Api\Source\BSN.IpTables.Cli\generated\generated\api\BsnIPTablesCli.cs`, like below

```cs
                var _url = new global::System.Uri($"{$host}{pathAndQuery}");
```

and this form of variable does not exist and invalid format in C#

**`BsnIPTablesCli.cs` is generated by `autorest.powershell` so I want to correct this problem with some way by autorest.powershell and I do not how to do it?**

My code exist in https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/pull/22

Comment: So.. Why not replace `{$host}` with something else like empty value using *replace* in any text editor?

Comment: @filimonic `BsnIPTablesCli.cs` is generated by `autorest.powershell` so I want to correct this problem with some way by autorest.powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [build module failed because invalid variable generated](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.powershell/issues/1246) GitHub ticket on [autorest.powershell](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.powershell), [dolauli](https://github.com/dolauli) says:

> @soroshsabz since you did not provide the swagger, I guess the root is you did not specify host in the swagger. And [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/baremetalinfrastructure/resource-manager/Microsoft.BareMetalInfrastructure/stable/2023-04-06/baremetalinfrastructure.json#L8) is an example.

So if you want to correct this problem, you need to add `host` into the `swagger.json` and for doing this as you can see in [How to add host variable in swagger json file at C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77408526/1539100) you need to add below code in swagger generation options on initializing swagger like below

```
            // Add host to generated swagger file (swagger.json)
            options.AddServer(new OpenApiServer {
                Url = "http://{serverAddress}",
                Description = "IpTables Test Server",
                Variables = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiServerVariable>
                {
                    { "serverAddress", new OpenApiServerVariable {
                                                Default = "192.168.21.56:8080",
                                                Description = "Target Server Address" }
                    }
                }
            });
```