# How to add host variable in swagger json file at C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I have a C# asp.net project based on .NET 6 and I want to generate swagger json file to implement client based on this file

In this situation I need to specify `host` variable to determine client how to connect server.

But my question is how to do this?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77339683/1539100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to add `host` variable into the json file

```
            // Add host to generated swagger file (swagger.json)
            options.AddServer(new OpenApiServer {
                Url = "http://{serverAddress}",
                Description = "IpTables Test Server",
                Variables = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiServerVariable>
                {
                    { "serverAddress", new OpenApiServerVariable {
                                                Default = "192.168.21.56:8080",
                                                Description = "Target Server Address" }
                    }
                }
            });
```

this options is for `SwaggerGenOptions` and you can set this in `program.cs` or `startup.cs` typically.